# Would it be OK to migrate this question here?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The question is:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14384/what-is-the-best-way-to-display-a-form-with-onetomany-fields

It's certainly off topic for Web Applications, it's just that I'm not certain it's a good fit for here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems fine to me. It's asking for a way to perform a specific task. We've got lots of questions like that right now.

Comment: It's just that I was burnt with a previous migration (not to here though) so I thought I'd double check).

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisF. Don't worry about getting burned here. You know this site. And at this point scope definition is a much less of a concern than having enough new questions to keep people engaged. I'd rather go faster at the risk of veering off the road a little bit.